# Sails.js restricting access thru policies

Tags: javascript, sails.js, ejs

I'm trying to restricting access having 3 parties, admin, user and visitor (they are not the member). I just want to get rid out of Register and Login header from html when admin and user logged in.

This is a front pages. session.usertype is an admin. session.userid is all the user who logged-in including the admin too

```
<% if(session.usertype) { %>
      <li><a href="/item">Item Manager</a></li>
      <li><a href="/category">Category Manager</a></li>
      <% } %>

      <li><a href="/Register">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>

      <% if(session.userid) {%>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><%= users.username %><span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="/profile">profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <% } %>
```

This is the controller

```
 login:function(req,res){
var username = req.param('username'); 
var password = req.param('password');
//findOne find only one data info that first found.
User.findOne({username:username,password:password}).exec(function(err, result){
  if(err){
    return res.send(err);
  }
  if(result){
    console.log(result);
    req.session.userid = result.id;
    req.session.usertype = result.type;
    return res.redirect('/diy');
  }
   return res.view('user/login',{error:"username or password incorrect"});
});
```

Pictures of results.

[This is visitor will see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT8dC.png)

But when I logged in as an admin

[I don't want that register and login after I logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EqvM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ejs will render

```
  <li><a href="/Register">Register</a></li>
  <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
```

in all conditions. You need to wrap it in the `else` condition.

```
<% if(session.usertype) { %>
      <li><a href="/item">Item Manager</a></li>
      <li><a href="/category">Category Manager</a></li>
      <% } else {%>

      <li><a href="/Register">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
<% } %>
```